# Can interfaces be used as datatypes just like String,int etc

Tags: java, class, android-studio, android-arrayadapter

I was searching the AdapterView.java class. And then I ran into this problem.I have uploaded the java file to the below link

```
https://www.codepile.net/pile/7J7xq0LY
```

Here `OnItemClickListener` is an interface(written on line 278). On line 146 it's given as `OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;`. How's is that possible .`mOnItemClickListener` is a member variable. Giving it next to an interface name does'nt make sense for me. When we declare a variable,we first write the variable type followed by the name. But here it doesn't make a logic. Can anyone please explain this to me. I have just learned about interfaces so not much confident with its basics. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the necessary code (as briefly as possible) in the question, not posted on some other site.

Comment: @user85421 Thanks. It was really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can interfaces be used as datatypes just like String,int etc.

Yes, an `interface` is also a type like a `class`. An `interface` reference is used in Java to achieve polymorphism.

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html) for more information.

Given below is a sample code to demonstrate this concept:

```
interface Polygon {
    double getArea();
}

class Triangle implements Polygon {
    private double base, height;

    public Triangle(double base, double height) {
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(double base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(double height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return 0.5 * base * height;
    }

}

class Rectangle implements Polygon {

    private double length, breadth;

    public Rectangle(double length, double breadth) {
        this.length = length;
        this.breadth = breadth;
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(double length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public double getBreadth() {
        return breadth;
    }

    public void setBreadth(double breadth) {
        this.breadth = breadth;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea() {
        return length * breadth;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Polygon shape1 = new Triangle(10, 20);
        Polygon shape2 = new Rectangle(10, 20);
        System.out.println(shape1.getArea());
        System.out.println(shape2.getArea());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
100.0
200.0
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: Thanks. Finally got what I was looking for

Comment: Sir can I consult you with similar doubts in future. I find your explanation really comfortable